# How Tuples can do the duty of Permutation?

Tags: list-manipulation

Please consider:

```
list1={0,0,0,0,0,0};
list2={1,1,1,1,1,1};
```

How can I access to the result of

```
Permutations[Flatten[{list1, list2}]]
(* {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, 
 {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, 
 {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1}, 
  {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1}, and so on*)
```

But by `Tuples`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not very efficient but straightforward

```
list1={0,0,0,0,0,0};
list2={1,1,1,1,1,1};
perm=Sort[Permutations[Flatten[{list1,list2}]]];
tupl=Sort[Select[Tuples[{0,1},12],Count[#,0]==6&]];
perm==tupl
```

> > True

Comment: It is good but I think because the code has to compute all elements in the `Tuples[{0,1},12]` and after that considers to `Count` it takes long for longer lists?!

Comment: @InzoBabaria that's why I said "Not very efficient".

Comment: Ok thank you so much.